# Scrapy project can't find django.core.management

Tags: django, scrapy, webfaction

I'm trying to follow the method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883196/saving-django-model-from-scrapy-project) to 'Scrapy' data from the web and simultaneously save that data directly to my Django database using Scrapy's item pipeline.

However, when I try to run `scrapy crawl spidername`, I'm getting the error:

`ImportError: No module named django.core.management`

At first I thought it was because my Scrapy project was outside of my Django project folder, but even after I moved the whole project into my Django project folder I kept getting the same error.  If I open a python shell inside the Scrapy project folder in its new location (inside my Django project folder), `import django.core.management` works fine.  So what's going on?

**EDIT:** Some additional info: I'm doing this on a Webfaction server, and the path to my Django project is `/home/gchorn/webapps/django_app/django_project`.  I'm using Django version 1.4.1, Scrapy 0.16 and Python2.7.  The layout of the Django+Scrapy project is as follows:

```
django_project/
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    myproject #folder containing wsgi.py
    app1
    app2
    app3
    templates
    ScrapyProject/
        scrapy.cfg
        ScrapyProject/
            __init__.py
            items.py
            pipelines.py
            settings.py
            spiders/
                __init__.py
                my_spider.py
```

Comment: Just to confirm, are you opening a simple Python interpreter or running "python manage.py shell"?

Comment: Talvalin, I'm just opening a simple 2.7 interpreter.

Comment: When you open the shell, is that using the same version of Python (2.7)?

Comment: @Dana, yes I'm just typing in `Python2.7` to open the shell.

Comment: What is the result of typing 'which python'?

Comment: @Talvalin, I get `/usr/local/bin/python` when typing `which python` in the top-level ScrapyProject directory (just inside my top-level Django project directory).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this in your Spider's settings.py:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/gchorn/webapps/django_app')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'
```

Then you can import your model classes like:

```
from django_project.app1.models import some_model
```